# How can I access Objects within a void method while unit testing?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, void

I am unit testing a Spring Boot service method. I have a void method with no args. It queries a db and gets a List. I can mock and assert on that. Then it runs through the list and changes object fields according to some condition. How can I check the contents of that list so I can assert on them?

```
@Transactional
public void someMethod() {
    List<Person> myList = repository.findAllByAge(0);
    myList.forEach(person -> person.setAge(18));
}
```

How can I assert on myList to check that each Person in myList with age 0 is getting set to age 18? I currently have this in my test class...

```
@Test
public void someMethod_withSuccess() {
    List<Person> testList = new ArrayList<>();
    testList.add(toPersonEntity(createPersonDto().setAge(0)));
    when(mockRepo.findAllByAge(0)).thenReturn(testList);

    mockService.someMethod();
}
```

Comment: Can you share some code so we can get a better idea of what you have and what you're trying to do?

Comment: When you mock that method you pass the result list that you are expecting. So assert on that result list for the changes you are expecting.

Comment: using ArgumentCaptor you can achieve this, post your code that can help to answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can call that method through [Reflection API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html).

btw, if you need to test this method, it probably has to be redisigned to be public or not tested at all.

Answer (score 0):

it is as easy as this

```
testList.forEach(person -> assertThat("person "+testList.indexOf(person),person.getAge(),equalTo(28)));
```